# can IPv6 eliminate mac address

Tags: networking, ip, ipv6

MAC address are used for uniquely identifying my computer.
IP address are used for routing the packets to the network, as it has got a hierarchial structure, but it doesn't uniquely identifies a computer. So, after IPv6, each computer will have a unique IP address, so will there be any need of MAC address then?
Please do correct me, if I had understood something wrong.

Answer (score 5):

No. MAC addresses operate at layer 2 ("[data link layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_link_layer)"). The Internet Protocol (both IPv4 and IPv6) operates at layer 3 ("[network layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_layer)").

These two layers are complimentary, and do not "replace" each other. For more information, read up on the [TCP/IP suite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite).

IPv6 stateless address autoconfiguration (SLAAC) uses the MAC address to generate the address, but that does not mean they "replace" each other. It's simply a characteristic of the layer 2 interface being inherited by the layer 3 addressing. Other than that, completely complimentary.